# Reducing Server response time - Send first bytes via echo?

Tags: php, performance

I'm trying to lower my Server response time. Right now it's about 1~2 seconds. Aiming for 0.3 seconds or lower.

My script can't be made any faster as it's necessarily resource intensive. I'm thinking if I echo "" as soon as the server is pinged, it would lover the server response time. So I placed an "echo "" on the top of the script - however this doesn't seem to be reducing the server response whatsoever.

What is the right solution in this case? I'm not keen on doing AJAX solutions as it would delay certain parts of the page and hence have SEO consequences

Comment: Why do you think that sending something immediately should lower your overall response time?

Comment: @Federkun My assumption was that if something is echoed as soon as the script runs, then it would reduce the "time to first byte"

Comment: No, that's not how http/tcp works

Comment: @Federkun Care to point me in the right direction? I'm lost and don't quite know what is the right question to ask.